# Root test for sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove  that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L$ implies $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} {a_{k}}^{1/k} = L$

This what I did:

By the limit definition, if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L $ then $\left | \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}- L \right | < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq m$. Therefore, it is also true that

$L - \epsilon < \dfrac{a_{m+1}}{a_m} < L + \epsilon$

$L - \epsilon < \dfrac{a_{m+2}}{a_{m+1}} < L + \epsilon$

$L - \epsilon < \dfrac{a_{m+4}}{a_{m+3}} < L + \epsilon$

$\quad \vdots$

$L - \epsilon < \dfrac{a_{k}}{a_{k-1}} < L + \epsilon$

Multiplying all inequalities and simplyfing:

$(L - \epsilon)^{k-m} < \dfrac{a_{k}}{a_{m}} < (L + \epsilon)^{k-m}$

and applying the k-root:

$(L - \epsilon)^{1-m/k} < \dfrac{{a_{k}}^{1/k}}{{a_{m}}^{1/k}} < (L + \epsilon)^{1-m/k}$

Since $m$ is fixed, taking the limit $k \to \infty$ we get

$ L - \epsilon < \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} < (L + \epsilon) $

My problem is I don't know how to justify from the last step that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} = L$. I asked myself that if I have $L-\epsilon < \lim a(n) < L+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ would imply $\lim a(n) = L$, but I couldn't get a good answer.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you are assuming the limit exists without proof.

However, we have for all $\epsilon > 0$,

$$L- \epsilon \leqslant \liminf_{ \,k \to \infty}  \,a_k^{1/k} \leqslant \limsup_{\,k \to \infty}\,a_k^{1/k} \leqslant L+\epsilon$$.

This proves (since assuming otherwise leads to a contradiction)

$$L = \liminf_{k \to \infty} \,a_k^{1/k} = \limsup_{k \to \infty}\,a_k^{1/k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k^{1/k}$$

Comment: Yeah, I understand your statement. But I would also say: If I have $L - \epsilon < \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} < (L + \epsilon)$, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily fixed, this implies $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} = L$, right?

Comment: You are trying to (1) establish that the limit exists, and (2) show that it equals $L$.  It all works out the way you say it, but it is intuitive based on what you have already shown. It is best not to pass to the limit without establishing first that it exists. You don't know that the sequence $a_k^{1/k}$ oscillates without a limit.  For example $-2 < (-1)^k < 2$ but that alone does not permit you to assert $-2 \leqslant \lim_{k \to \infty}(-1)^k \leqslant 2$.

Comment: If I know that $x_k < y_k$ for all sufficiently large $k$  and $y_k \to L$, then given this information the most I can conclude is $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \, x_k \leqslant L$.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Indeed, I didn't show the limit exists. With your statement I can show it exists and leads to be $L$. But what if I was told the limit already exists? Can I justify from the fact that, the limit already exists plus $L - \epsilon < \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} < (L + \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$  arbitrarily fixed that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}{a_{k}}^{1/k} = L$? My main problem is to know under what circumstances I can assure from $L-\epsilon < a(n) < L+\epsilon)$ that $a(n)=L$. I think I can assure it if $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily fixed.

Comment: Suppose $a(n) > L$.  Take $\epsilon' = (a(n) -L)/2$. The we get a contradiction $L + \epsilon ' < a(n)$ because $a(n) < L + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  Similarly we get a contradiction if $a(n) < L$.  The only possible conclusion is $a(n) = L$.

Comment: .. and I'm not sure why you are writing $a(n)$.  If the limit exists and falls between $L \pm \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ as you showed, then the limit equals $L$.